# mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL

Tags: linux, mysql

I'm running a MySql Server and a dotnet core service on a single core 1GB RAM server.
I realized that our service throws mysql connection errors. After a little bit of investigating i found that mysql service is killed by the system.

I increased the server RAM and CPU to 2 core 4 GB, still getting this error. Not that often but i still get this error.

What might be the problem?

Best regards!

```
journalctl -u mysql
```

outputs:

```
Aug 17 06:18:59 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 06:19:01 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 11:20:22 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 17 11:20:22 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 17 11:20:22 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Aug 17 11:20:22 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 11:20:22 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 11:20:24 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 12:45:04 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 17 12:45:04 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 17 12:45:05 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Aug 17 12:45:05 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 12:45:05 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 12:45:07 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 14:27:14 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 17 14:27:14 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 17 14:27:14 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Aug 17 14:27:14 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 17 14:27:14 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 17 14:27:15 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 06:54:12 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 18 06:54:12 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 18 06:54:12 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 18 06:54:12 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 06:54:12 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 18 06:54:14 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 11:17:09 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 18 11:17:09 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Aug 18 11:17:09 servername systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 18 11:17:09 servername systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 18 11:17:09 servername systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 18 11:17:11 servername systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: thats not showing the error. Please provide the output of the error logs instead the startup log of journal

Comment: Error log file `/var/log/mysql/error.log` is empty. Gzipped log files are empty also

Comment: Please follow up the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/debugging-server.html) for start debugging - also reference to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/71071/how-to-enable-mysql-logging)

Comment: Please post TEXT result of A) SELECT @@version;  B) HTOP results 1st page or TOP results 1st page.  Welcome to SF.

Comment: Since you do NOT have an error log, Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
for Error Log Setup analysis to find out WHY and provide suggestions.